# Background color is not working only on my server

Tags: html, css

```css
.header {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header>ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav">

    <!--white logo part-->
    <li><span class="logo">@Brightest East</span></li>

    <!--username part-->
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; <?php if($_COOKIE['hwi']){echo $_COOKIE['hwi'];} ?></a></li>

    <!--log out part-->
    <li><a href="logout.php?logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp; Logout</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Background color is not working on my server.

everything is just white and on left.

Even if In my css code, i chose background color is black and right.

Comment: link to your website?

Comment: Are you getting any `404` errors in console...

Comment: No, other things are working properly and it's my website link http://www.brightesteast.pe.hu/main.php

Comment: @MehulMohan Why would you undo the snippet?

Comment: @j08691 snippets are meant for working HTML/CSS code. OP's code is PHP. Moreover it worked fine here, so not really a big advantage of runnable example

Comment: @MehulMohan The PHP is irrelevant here and the code given could easily be runnable. And since it runs fine in a snippet, it invalidates the answer you posted.

Comment: I think the issue is with how you are linking your CSS sheet. You are defining a CSS sheet but linking to an SCSS file - Might be the main cause of your issue

Comment: @j08691 No problem. I just thought that the code was infact working here. So it'll be best to see the live website to find actual issue. I've rolled back

Comment: @j08691 Why does this invalidate my answer? The answer aims to solve problem live on the website, not the problem in snippet

Comment: @MehulMohan It invalidates your answer because the code the OP posted works and needs no modifications. If the code the user posted doesn't capture the actual problem, then they need to post a [mcve] that does.

Comment: @MikeDiglio Thank you, you were right. it worked

Comment: @j08691 duh.. okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS to your site:

```
.header:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

You're not clearing the `ul` floats in your header.